# ‘Inoculum’ vs ‘inoculant’ – which one is it?

Tags: terminology

I’m currently writing the report of a study which looked at commercial soil inoculants *(Rhizobium sp.)*. However, I’m confused about the differences between the words *inoculum* and *inoculant* and when to use which.

Comment: ask on http://english.stackexchange.com/ please

Comment: If the dictionary definitions do not tell you which one to use, I doubt anyone at english.se would know either.

Comment: In my opinion, dictionary definitions are not helpful in this case as it is an idiomatic problem. Therefore I was hoping to get some information from people who are also using these words in academia. Inoculants are used in a variety of research fields, hence it is likely that I would find help here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the english language.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I disagree. There are a number of people over at english.se who write some excellent answers about usage, suffixes, and the like. I expect that's the best SE site for this question about when to use the direct latin ending inoculum, vs. the suffix -ant

Comment: Further to @DeNovo, I would say that on SE English Language and Usage you will be expected to provide a sample sentence in which you wish to use the word. You will also be expected to report what you found in dictionaries and explain why it didn't help. It would help to know what the leading scientific journals are in your field, so that anyone with access to a (e.g. University) subscription can search for actual usage of the word if you cannot. Also [Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) may be a useful tool for that in relation to books.